# After adding record PHP return to previous page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have 2 PHP pages. One in the "add.php" page and the other is the "proccess.php" page. The "process.php" is simply the php the saves the added record to mysql database.

After the record is saved, I have the following to go to specific page after record is saved.

```
header('Refresh: 3; URL=edit/edit.php');
```

Rather then do this, I would like it to go back to the previous page "add.php". But I don't want to specify the page, just tell it to go back 1 page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Note that this may not work with secure pages (HTTPS) and it's a pretty bad idea overall as the header can be hijacked.

---

Or this one:

```
header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually it needs to go back 2 pages. Sorry about that:(

Comment: You just need to change the second one as history.go(-2). Not sure about how to do it with $_SERVER.

Comment: What if the user has javascript disabled?

Comment: The 2nd option doesn't seem to work. Is that ok to use within PHP?